# Javascript link will not work without # at the end of the url

Tags: javascript

I am creating a very simple login site for a school project, and the site is therefore the most basic you can make it.

When the `window.location.assing` link is activated, it will only work if the current url I am on has a # at the end. E.G. ... project/test.html#.

The rest of the script is perfectly fine. It is only the linking that does not work.

I am working in a local file so I am trying to go from

```
C:\Users\Tord\Documents\IT\Skryteprosjekt\test.html
```

to

```
C:\Users\Tord\Documents\IT\Skryteprosjekt\1.html
```

I have searched around a lot, but can not find an answer that fits my problem.

The function is being called by an onclick in a button in HTML.

```
function login() {
  var x = document.getElementById("username").value;

  if (x == "example") {
    var y = document.getElementById("psw").value;
    if (y == "example2") {
      window.location.assign("1.html");
    }
    else {
      alert("Incorrect username or password. Try again.");
    }
  }

  else if (x == "") {
    alert("Please write in a username and password");
  }
  else {
    alert("Incorrect username or password. Try again");
  }
}
```

When I activate the script with the correct username and password, the site just blinks as if it just reloads. Everything else works perfectly.

Comment: Hash is just a blank anchor

Comment: Is your button calling this function correctly ?

Comment: What do you mean the "site blinks"?

Comment: How is the `login` function being called?

Comment: It should go without saying, using client side code to verify login is a bad idea because your passwords are ultimately in clear text (among many other reasons). Depending on how serious this project is, you may want to reconsider how you go about securing the page.

Comment: Editing the question continuosly as i get questions here. And sorry for my English, I am  Norwegian.

Comment: Don't worry about your English, it's fine. There could be a number of things that might be influencing the behaviour. Some further things to check: 1) Is the behaviour consistent across multiple browsers? 2) What tag is this "button"? Is it an anchor (<a>) or a button/input, or something else entirely? 3) Please provide the full URL path that this page is at and the full URL path you are trying to navigate to. 4) Would you be able to provide a full reproducible sample? Either via git or a fiddle or something?

Comment: Does anything change if you just use `window.location.href = "1.html";` instead of the assign method?

Comment: Changing to window.location.href works only if the url of the login site itself has a # at the end

Comment: Are you able to replicate that issue with minimal code in an online editor? It would be really helpful to get hands on with working code. A good editor (IMO) would be [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)